# Could not build module "Darwin" in Xcode 14

Tags: ios, react-native

[image]

I could not figure out this issue. The answers in the forum are outdated and very old. This issue is occurred when I try to build for Iphone 14 pro in simulator. My react native version is 0.67.2.

**React Native Info**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.3.1
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M2 Pro
    Memory: 1.12 GB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.1.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 9.6.6 - ~/Desktop/patiwe/node_modules/.bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.05.15.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 14.3.1/14E300b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.67.2 => 0.67.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```